# Canvas toDataURL returns empty/damaged

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas on my page that allows visitors to draw something.
I now want to add a download button that saves the drawing but the saved png is always empty/damaged: "The file "image.png" could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise."

What did I do wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<a href="" id="downloader" onclick="download()" download="image.png">Save</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById('c');
    var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
    onmousemove = function(e) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 15;
        ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function download(){
        document.getElementById("downloader").download = "image.png";
        document.getElementById("downloader").href = document.getElementById("c").toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing capture code which i used in my project, I hope you you understand it.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("#cv1");`
```

var glastbloburl;

function proc_cature(){

```
if(!canvas)return; 

if(!window.URL){

    alert("This browser does not support.");

    return;

}

var strMime, filename;

if(g_lastdata2 && g_lastdata2.resp){

    filename=getfilename(g_lastdata2.resp.title);

}

if(!filename) filename='Capture';

if(_getid('capturekind').value=='png'){

    strMime="image/png";

    filename+=".png";       

}else{

    strMime="image/jpeg";

    filename+=".jpg";

}

var strData=canvas.toDataURL(strMime);

var blob=b64toBlob(strData.substr(strData.indexOf(",")+1,strData.length), strMime);

if(glastbloburl) window.URL.revokeObjectURL(glastbloburl);

glastbloburl=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var s='<a href="#" id="capturedown">Download</a> &nbsp;<a href="'+glastbloburl+'" target="_blank">View</a> '+getsize(blob.size);
_getid('msg5').innerHTML=s;
var blobLink=_getid('capturedown');
if(blobLink){
    blobLink.onclick=function(){
        if(navigator.msSaveBlob){
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            return false;
        }else{
            blobLink.download = filename;
            if(issafari){
                window.open(glastbloburl);
                return false;
            }else{
                blobLink.target='_blank';
                blobLink.href=glastbloburl;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hi, thanks for sharing your code and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: i tried implementing your code but i couldn't figure out how to add the download link. i tried this link <a href="" id="blobLink">Save</a> but when i click on it, it refreshes the page.